# Is there a difference between rejection of a belief, and withholding judgement? Does rejection of a belief B, mean ¬B or does it mean a lack of B?

Tags: logic, belief

Is there a difference between rejection of a belief, and withholding judgement?  Does  rejection of a belief  B, mean ¬B or does it mean a lack of B?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123965/discussion-on-question-by-barlop-is-there-a-difference-between-rejection-of-a-be).

Answer (score 2):

Belief in the truth of a proposition is a statement independent of it's actual truth. Consider the fact that different people can have different beliefs about B while B is either true or not, unrelated to what people believe about it. Also "Jack believes today is may the 4th" is a statement about Jack, not about today's date.

To represent it formally you would need some kind of function like notation belief(B), or even belief(Jack, B). Then contrast the four possibilities:

**i**) belief(B) → *Jack believes B is true*
**j**) belief(¬B) → *Jack believes B is false*
**k**) ¬belief(B) → *Jack does not believe B is true*
**l**) ¬belief(¬B) → *Jack does not believe B is false*

Note that **i** and **k**, **j** and **l** respectively are contradictory, as per the definition of ¬.

Then by any sensible definition of the function "belief", **i** and **j** are contradictory, **i** ⇒ **l** and **j** ⇒ **k**, but **k** and **l** can be both true (*Jack has no opinion on B*).

So it can be seen that ¬belief(B), belief(¬B) and ¬B are 3 very different statements.

Comment: What about the distinctions made: not b, lack of b and b itself?  You address only the not variation. Would you admit the non or lack of b is the same Mathematical idea as NOT B as found on your notation?  There is no way to distinguish lack of or a NON in math. For instance Theist is distinct from ATHIEST which is distinct from AGNOSTIC which would be the non theist here. You simply define lack of as a not as a straight rejection. Here you say they are identical. The problem is people tend to always think lack of is a negation always. This is not always true and people need to be aware.

Comment: I actually state that belief(B) is a statement about the believer, not B. ¬belief(B) (agnostic), belief(¬B) (hard atheist) and ¬B (a statement about the universe itself) are 3 very different statements. I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: @Logikal  In Logic the lack of a belief B, is written by simply not listing it in your premises, as opposed to writing ¬B.   Though I guess if you really don't have anything about B in your premises then you'd not have B and you'd not have ¬B  so you wouldn't really have a view on it, wouldn't have considered the preposition, or you'd be 50/50, or at least too unsure to say one way or the other.

Comment: @barlop, what you meant to say is Mathematical logic. There are distinct types of so called LOGIC. You saying LOGIC doesn't really say much as me saying I live on Earth is not saying that much. It is better to be specific than vague. In math perhaps you would not list a non b. In philosophy you should list a non b as a premise to avoid people jumping to conclusions with little information. You are purposely omitting facts by not listing the premise. This of course can deceive people by you cherry picking premises. This would be challenged in both Philosophy & Rhetoric. Math is different.

Comment: First-order logic doesn't let you write something like belief(¬B), because the domain of discourse generally does not include complex propositions like ¬B. IMHO you may need to start getting into modal logic to properly model this. Or else you need to use a higher-order logic to allow predicates that range over other predicates, but that's ugly.

Comment: (k) and (l) are not contradictory. For example, I have no reason to believe that Joe Biden watched TV yesterday. I also have no reason to believe that Joe Biden didn't watch TV yesterday. If I have no knowledge about something, then it is reasonable not to belief that it is true, and not to belief that it is false.

Comment: @gnasher729 yeah, that's kind of exactly what is meant by "but k and l can be both true (Jack has no opinion on B)."

Answer (score 1):

A common view in epistemology distinguishes four different states with respect to a given proposition p:

1. Believing that p
2. Disbelieving that p
3. Suspending judgment on whether p
4. Lack of belief with respect to p

To disbelieve that p, on this view, is to simply believe that p is false. Suspending judgment is neither believing nor disbelieving - it is taking no stance one way or the other. It is distinguished from lack of belief, which is simply having no attitude toward p. A reason for that is as follows: it is seems incorrect to say, for example, that Plato suspended judgment on whether iPhones are better than Android devices. Rather, he lacked any such belief. To suspend judgment in this sense means that the question is still open for you.

It is less standard to talk about 'rejection'. Conceivably someone can reject a statement because they believe it is false, or reject it because there isn't enough evidence to decide it one way or the other, in which case they might suspend judgment and not have a belief that it is false.

A recent influential defense of this view is by Jane Friedman, ["Suspended Judgment"](https://philpapers.org/rec/FRISJ) *Philosophical Studies* 162 (2):165-181 (2013).

Comment: The concept of REJECTION in the rational sense doesn't have multiple meanings. For one one can't say they are rational & at the same time say they reject x without some familiarity with x. In this way, if I reject x I have some fair idea what x is. For me to have total ignorance of x & claim to reject x is a bit odd. Secondly, most people reject something like x because there is not enough evidence which correlates why they think x is false. To them if you don't provide evidence they will just reject x simply because they can. That would be irrational. Can  you can distinguish 3 & 4 above?